# What is the Browser version of a WebBrowser control in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm building a Windows Forms application which makes use of the WebBrowser control.  Can anyone tell me what rendering engine the control uses?

Is it fixed based on the version of the .NET framework I'm developing against or is it based on the version of IE installed on the client's machine?  Does the client even need IE?

In other words, if a website looks right in my application on my machine, is it reasonably safe to assume it'll render right on everyone else's machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be the version of IE installed on the target machine.  There can only be one, IE doesn't support side-by-side installation of versions.  You don't know for a fact your app will work without issue unless you test it on different machines that have versions 6, 7 and 8 installed.  This is normally the burden of the web site author.

Comment: Just what I wanted to know - thanks! We're developing a site specifically to be loaded into this control. The web guys will be delighted to hear they still need to test in IE6!! ;o)

Comment: [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements/) msdn says that *"For compatibility purposes, the WebBrowser control will run in IE7 Standards Mode by default if no Feature Control Key value is defined for an application."* How does your statement goes with that? If I have IE11 installed on the machine running the app with WebBrowser, and no Feature Control Key was specified, nor any meta compatibility tags (which by the way do not seem to be having an effect in my case) - you disagree and claim the IE version WebBrowser will run is 11, instead of 7 ?

Comment: You have IE11, it *emulates* the quirks of IE7.  The FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry key can be used to alter or disable this emulation.

Comment: The app that is running an instance of WebBrowser is facing javascript errors. If I open up the page with IE11, no errors. If I go to Emulation (F12) and change Document mode to IE7, I get those same javascript errors. If WB defaults to the latest IE installed on machine, then it must run IE11. And I should not be facing errors. If I am, and they are the same when I emulate IE7, I must assume that it is not using IE11. Wrong ?

Comment: Luckily you actually have IE11 on the machine so you can very easily fix the problem by editing the registry.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the registry key, otherwise the webBrowser will render as IE4

See here:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Registry Key Location for FEATURE_BROWSER EMULATION
You can specify these keys in the registry at:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
The HKCU key is the best place to set these values because there's a single key and it can be set without admin rights, but you can also set these keys at the machine level at HKLM:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
or for a 32 bit application on a 64 bit machine:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

**Key Name**
The keyname is the EXE name of your application like:

outlook.exe
MarkdownMonster.exe

**Values**

The value specifies the IE version as follows:

The value to set this key to is (taken from MSDN here) as decimal values:

11001 (0x2AF9)
Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

11000 (0x2AF8)
Internet Explorer 11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.

10001 (0x2AF7)
Internet Explorer 10. Webpages are displayed in IE10 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

10000 (0x2710)
Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.

9999 (0x270F)
Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

9000 (0x2328)
Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.

8888 (0x22B8)
Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.

8000 (0x1F40)
Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode.

7000 (0x1B58)
Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. This mode is kind of pointless since it's the default.

Setting these keys enables your applications to use the latest Internet Explorer versions on your machine easily. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a key that says use the latest version that's installed - you have to be specific regarding the version unfortunately. Given that Windows 7 and later can run IE 11, I'm requiring users to have IE 11 if I want to use HTML5 and more advanced CSS features like Flexbox, but if your content is simpler you can probably get away with using IE 10 or even IE 9.